# OpenShift: Multiple post requests from nodejs being fired

Tags: javascript, node.js, openshift, onesignal, requestjs

I am trying out the OpenShift cloud server with a nodejs instance.
I am trying to perform a POST request to the oneSignal API.

The POST is successful but oneSignal sends 4 notifications for a single POST.

I think I have isolated that the issue is with the OpenShift server because when I run the following code on my local machine, I receive a single notification but when the code is deployed on OpenShift, I get 4 notifications.

Below is the test code:

```
var request = require('request');

function sendNotification() { 
    var data = {};
    data.headings = {"en": "Trial Push Heading"}
    data.contents = {"en": "Trial Push Contents"};

    data.app_id = MY_APP_ID;
    data.included_segments = ["All"];


    var headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": "Basic "+ MY_AUTH_KEY
    };

    var options = {
        url: "https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications",
        method: "POST",
        headers: headers,
        json: data
    }; 

    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body) // Print the shortened url.
      }
    });


};
```

Answer (score 1):

Well...

Answering my own question..

OpenShift initializes the code from start.js.

Start.js implements node clustering and creates 4 instances of app.js . This is causing multiple post requests.